# Wishlist ajax remove

Tags: magento2.3, controllers, backend, wishlist, interceptor

I want to remove product from wishlist from a custom button on detail. I did a plugin for the `Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Remove.php` with an `aroundExecute` but for some reason I can't load/create products as magento does in the default Remove controller. I posted my file

```
 use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
    use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface;
    use Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item;
    use Magento\Wishlist\Model\Product\AttributeValueProvider;
    use Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory;

/**
 * Class Remove
 * @package Codesicle\WishlistAjax\Plugin\Wishlist\Controller\Index
 */
class Remove
{
    /**
     * @var WishlistProviderInterface
     */
    protected $wishlistProvider;

    /**
     * @var AttributeValueProvider
     */
    private $attributeValueProvider;


    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    protected $jsonFactory;

    /**
     * @var WishlistFactory
     */
    protected $wishlistFactory;

    public function __construct(
        WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider,
        AttributeValueProvider $attributeValueProvider = null,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
        Session $customerSession,
        WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory
    )
    {
        $this->wishlistProvider = $wishlistProvider;
        $this->attributeValueProvider = $attributeValueProvider
            ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(AttributeValueProvider::class);
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;
    }

    public function aroundExecute($subject, $proceed)
    {

        $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('item');

        $item = $subject->_objectManager->create(Item::class)->load($id);

        if (!$item->getId()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
        }
        $wishlist = $this->wishlistProvider->getWishlist($item->getWishlistId());
        if (!$wishlist) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
        }
        try {
            $item->delete();
            $wishlist->save();
            $productName = $this->attributeValueProvider
                ->getRawAttributeValue($item->getProductId(), 'name');

            $response = [
                'errors' => false,
                'message' => __('%1 has been removed from your Wish List.', $productName)
            ];
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $exception) {
            $response = [
                'errors' => true,
                'message' => __('We can\'t delete the item from Wish List right now because of an error: %1.', $exception->getMessage())
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $response = [
                'errors' => true,
                'message' => __('We can\'t delete the item from the Wish List right now.')
            ];
        }
        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data::class)->calculate();

        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        return $resultJson->setData($response);
    }
```

What am I missing or what did I do wrong?

LE:

Looks like the `getItem` method from WishlistFactory is returning `NULL` and I can't get to find out why

Comment: Which error it show?

Comment: I get 500 error on the Post request. from some debugging the problem seems to be here or below `$subject->_objectManager->create(Item::class)->load($id)` but as I said this is how magento does it

Comment: Create _objectManager then use into your code.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I did that and still not working I used `$this->_objectManager = $context->getObjectManager();` in the constructor and still I get 500 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I changed the implementation a bit, there was a problem with the `getItem()` method and I went with the following

1. get current customer ID 
   `$customerId = $this->_session->getCustomerId();`
2. get wishlist by customer ID
   `$wishlist = $this->_wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);` I had to set `create` to true here otherwise the collection was not returning, only wishlist info like ID , name , etc.
3. get item from that collection
   `$item = $wishlist->getItem($id);`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you pass parameter of class `AttributeValueProvider` with `null` default value. The problem should be caused by the way you pass this parameter in dependency injection. So that when you call `$this->attributeValueProvider->getRawAttributeValue($item->getProductId(), 'name')` PHP will throw fatal error, because the dependency injection does not pass the `AttributeValueProvider` instance.

Try removing the `null` default value while passing `AttributeValueProvider` instance by changing `AttributeValueProvider $attributeValueProvider = null` to `AttributeValueProvider $attributeValueProvider`.

If problem persists, try removing the generated interceptor of your class:
`rm generated/code/Codesicle/WishlistAjax/Plugin/Wishlist/Controller/Index/Remove/Interceptor.php`, and retry deleting wishlist item.

Comment: that is not the problem, I tried your version but that was how magento-wishlist module gets the `attributeValueProvider` for some reason the `getItem` from the Wishlist model is returning `NULL` but I can't get to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

I would approach to this problem with a different way. When I create a plugin, I always try to focus on the purpose, rather than the result. There can be multiple ways to reach the expected result, but which one would serve the purpose the most?

The purpose here is **to return a custom JSON response instead of a redirect**. It is not to rewrite a core process to remove a wishlist item.

Here is a working example, giving the same result you are trying to achieve:

```
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\MessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory;
use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Remove as Subject;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

/**
 * Class Remove
 */
class Remove
{
    /**
     * @var LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $layoutFactory;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    protected $jsonFactory;

    /**
     * Remove constructor.
     * @param LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
     * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param JsonFactory $jsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param Subject $controller
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json
     */
    public function afterExecute(Subject $controller, $result)
    {
        $messages = $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);
        $messagesBlock = $this->layoutFactory->create()->getMessagesBlock();
        $messagesBlock->setMessages($messages);

        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $resultJson->setData([
            'errors' => boolval($messages->getCountByType(MessageInterface::TYPE_ERROR)),
            'message' => trim(strip_tags($messagesBlock->getGroupedHtml()))
        ]);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

***NOTE:*** By using the code above, you will need to post `form_key` parameter too along with the `item` parameter, as it's validated on the default controller unlike your example code. It may make your job easier to remove that validation, but it is highly unadvised to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **: Tested Code**

Note :**Just pass productId parameter in your ajax call** & **Logged User Id** Automatically **fetch from the Session**

```
class WishlistRemoveItems extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $wishlist;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $customerId =  $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        $productId = $this->request->getPostValue('productId');
        $wish = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
        $items = $wish->getItemCollection();

        /** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $item */
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) {
                $item->delete();
                $wish->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

hope it will help you, Thanks